# Search command in history from drop down list

Tags: command-line

Search in command line history using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is nice, but it shows only one line. It would be more convenient to have something like a drop down list of items for a given search condition. Is such a solution available?

Comment: Hi vico, just curious, but did you try the answer(s)?

Comment: Actually, answer suggested by Bruni is fast solution and does what is needed. Your answer is interesting solution I'm trying to get some free time to try it. Let you know as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. It does not exist as far as I know,

BUT...

like always, it can be made.

#### The solution, what it is

If you run e.g. (on my system):

```
$ search_history aap
```

`~/.bash_history` is searched for matches:

```
[1] printf aap
[2] echo aap
[3] du -sh '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/aap' 
[4] echo "een aap op een fiets" | awk '{ print $1 }'
[5] sudo chown root '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/aap' 
[6] yad --entry-text=aap
[7] python3 -c "[print(round(float(n)), end=' ') for n in open('test2').read().split()]" > aap
[8] python '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/aap' 


press the number of the line + ENTER to execute, or x to exit:
```

As the text sais, press the number to execute the corresponding command in the current terminal, or `x` to exit.

#### The setup

1. The script(s) need `xdotool` to "type" the commands into the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Create, if it does not exist, the directory `~/bin`
3. Copy script 1 into an empty file, save it as `search_history` (no extension) in `~/bin`
4. Copy script 2 into an empty file, save it as `type_command.sh` (with extension)
5. ***Make both scripts executable***
6. To "activate" the directory `~/bin` in `$PATH`, either:

   - log out/in, or
   - run `source ~/.bashrc`

#### The script(s)

*script 1*
*searches `~/.bash_history` for lines, matching (containing) the searched string, creates a numbered list in the terminal*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys

s = sys.argv[1]
lines = [l for l in open(os.environ["HOME"]+"/.bash_history").read().splitlines() if s in l]
if len(lines) == 0:
    print("no matches")
else:
    for i, l in enumerate(lines):
        print("["+str(i+1)+"]", l)
    nextact = input("\npress the number of the line + ENTER to execute, or x to exit: ")
    if nextact == "x":
        pass
    else:
        # not using try/except because if an error occurs, you might want to know the cause
        subprocess.Popen(["type_command.sh", lines[int(nextact)-1]])
```

*script 2*
*types the corresponding command. This has to be another (second) script, since we need to exit the first script to be able to run the command inside the terminal, just like a typed command.*

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 0.2
xdotool type "$1"
xdotool key KP_Enter
```

[image]

#### Note

in case you'd prefer to skip duplicate- lines, change in script 1 the line:

```
lines = [l for l in open(os.environ["HOME"]+"/.bash_history").read().splitlines() if s in l]
```

into:

```
lines = [l for l in set(open(os.environ["HOME"]+"/.bash_history").read().splitlines()) if s in l]
```

Comment: Why do you need `xdotool` for this? O.o Or Python?

Comment: @muru, since the command is run in the terminal as if it was typed, the first script has to end first, then xdotool does the typing. Not sure what you mean?

Comment: So? You do need to get out of the `xdotool` world sometimes, you know. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4201274/2072269

Comment: @muru I will definitely read throught the link. I don't see the downside of `xdotool` though, and it woks perfectly.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. But this, is handled within the shell - that's perfect. There's no need for a tool that runs outside the terminal - which can be foiled by something.

Comment: What's the saying? When the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail?

Comment: @muru I looked into the link. Seriously, I don't see how this would replace `xdotool` in the answer, or I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I would install [history suggest box](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) from [Martin Dvorak](https://www.linkedin.com/in/martindvorak). I use it on all my machines. As you type a string it shows you all commands included in your history including those strings. Results are by default sorted by how often you use them. You can navigate with the arrows. It is very flexible.

Installation on Ubuntu is simple, though you will have to add his ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hh
```

The program is invoked with hh.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: `history | grep keyword`